# CF10 web service error after updating to Java 8 v 60

Tags: java, coldfusion, ssl-certificate, coldfusion-10

I have a web service that had been working fine while we were on Java 7 version 75.  We recently updated to Java 8 and now we are getting this error on the web service:  *PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

This is the full dump:

```
   Charset  [empty string]
   ErrorDetail  I/O Exception: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   Filecontent  Connection Failure
   Header   [empty string]
   Mimetype Unable to determine MIME type of file.
   Responseheader  ws dump - struct [empty]
   Statuscode   Connection Failure. Status code unavailable.
   Text YES
```

We have updated the certificates and the certificates have been re-imported in the correct key store and verified it's there using keytool -list and restarted, but still get the authentication error.

I see this is usually fixed by re-installing the certificate but that hasn't worked.  Many suggestions to fix this error recommended installing Certman in CF Admin.  We installed it and imported the certificates, but still the same error.  Our workaround is rolling back to Java 7 version 75 so this web service works, but we need to update to the latest version of Java soon so our charts can work again and obviously for security reasons. Any suggestions?

Stats:

Java Dev Kit 8 v 60, 
ColdFusion 10 hotfix 17, 
Windows Server 8

****UPDATE*****
After reading Sean Coyne's answer below I talked to our Network Admin's.  They had already copied the tools.jar file into the lib folder.  They deleted the stubs folder and restarted the CF server, but we still got the same error.    I visited with them and they showed me that the certificates were indeed in the keystore.

As described here: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-troubleshooting-scheduled-tasks.html
We added some debugging to jvim.config as I ran the web service.  The debugging pointed out that the handshake with one of the certificates was invalid.  What the heck!

I asked if we could see the certs in the Certificate Manager in CF Admin.  It was NOT installed after all.  So the NA installed the [CertMan](http://certman.riaforge.org/) add on in CF Admin. After importing the certificates using CertMan and restarting the CF server, the web service worked after that.

I think doing what Sean Coyne suggested below AND making sure CertMan was installed so we could import the certificates was what fixed it for us.

Comment: have you reported to https://bugbase.adobe.com?

Comment: I did not report this in bugbase.   I wanted to see if anyone had some suggestions.  My last resort would be reporting it in bugbase.

Comment: On the plus side, Certificate Management is coming to a CF Admin natively...at some point...https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4011401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to delete the stubs.  These are in `[cfroot]/cfusion/stubs`.  Just stop CF, delete all the files in that directory and start CF again.

Also, you will want to copy the tools.jar file from your JDK installation into the lib folder at `[cfroot]/cfusion/lib/tools.jar`.  Backup the existing tools.jar file first then copy from `[jdk root]/lib/tools.jar`.

Reference: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-and-11-support-with-java-8

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because I think both the suggestions you made AND making sure the certificates are imported through CertMan are what fixed it for us.